What are the differences between the different conditional forms?
To my understanding, it is as follows:
(sentence)と、(sentence)
If this happens, this will be a natural consequence
(casual past tense)ら、(sentence)
If this has already happened, this is what should be done
(仮定形)ば、(sentence)
If this is true, this will be the follow through
(sentence)なら、(sentence)
If this is what you said you're gonna do, this may or may not be what that will add up to
Is there more to this, that needs to be understood?
